# Realistic maximum limit for number of commercial cloud VMs to start in one batch

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

We are developing an engineering tool for analysis and simulation of wind turbines. An important use case is to run 1000s of (independent) simulations as fast as possible (called a batch). We want to do this on commercial cloud VMs (AWS, Azure, Google). We are wondering if it is realistic to start 1000 or more VMs in one go (and run them for 30-60 minutes)?

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow, as it's unrelated to programming. That said: By listing a bunch of cloud vendors, and asking where it's realistic to do this, it becomes a tool recommendation question, which is off-topic.

Comment: You may enjoy reading this relevant case study. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/what-would-you-do-with-100000-cores-big-compute-at-global-scale/

Comment: Thanks, Greg. Very interesting and spot on.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the exact solutions that cloud computing can solve because all of the large vendors have spare capacity in the regions of tens of thousands of cores.

They all have case studies showing this capacity, all with thousands of VMs running large, clustered applications.

The best approach is to come up with a 'small' simulation that you can deploy to test the environment, perhaps on a few hundred cores. Carefully spec it out - maybe engage with some of the HPC specialist consultancies. Then once you have a pitch for the number of processors you need, the amount of IO, the speed of network between clusters etc. Give each of their sales teams a call and start a discussion.

If you don't go through this route, you can simply raise a support call to have your VM limit raised (this applies to all vendors) at that point you would explain your requirements and they'll get back in touch and work out how to deliver your requirements.